# correcting captured dvb-t video from two different mpeg-ts sources

Tags: merge, stream, ffmpeg, mpeg, dvb

I have captured same channel (two files - full multiplex of dvb-t - mpeg-ts) from different dvb-t transmitters:

Transmitter-A.ts
 Transmitter-B.ts

I would like to merge these streams to produce one perfect video of channel to correct failtures in signal from transmitter-B and transmitter-A - I know there are frame gaps lets say:

Transmitter-A.ts 1:10-1:20
Transmitter-B.ts 2:30-2:35

Is there some existing tool to do so? Do I have to go to the frame level of ts packet and compare them between streams(lets say find I-frames-will they fit? And compare them)? I hoped pts and dts timestamps would fit but didnt - is there some way to use pcr or any stamp in ts packet preventing me to go on frame level?